# Javascript Custom Validator: duplicate error message

Tags: javascript, validation, file-upload

I've got a custom validator on a file upload that checks the file size. The validation works correctly, and it displays the error message in the validation summary like its supposed to, but it *also* displays it next to the upload control itself. Further, this error message never goes away, even if the upload control is valid:

[image: Inline error message shouldn't be there]
[image: Even after I resolve the issue, the inline error is still there]
I'm not sure how the inline error message is getting there, or how to get rid of it. Here's my control:

```
<div class="tblCell" id="celUpl6">
<asp:FileUpload ID="uplCollection6" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="formfield" />
<a onclick="clearFileInputField('celUpl6')" href="javascript:noAction();" class=" linkButton">REMOVE</a>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvUpl6" runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="- Too big!"
    ControlToValidate="uplCollection6"
    Display="Static"
    ClientValidationFunction="validateFileSize6" ValidationGroup="vgRegForm"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

And here are my validation functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
    if (typeof (ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) {
        for (var i in Page_Validators) {
            try {
                var control = document.getElementById(Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate);
                if (!Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {
                    control.className = " validator-controls-error";
                } else {
                    control.className = "formfield";
                }
            } catch (e) { }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```
function getFileSize(uploaderName) {
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var filepath = document.getElementById(uploaderName).value;
    var thefile = fso.getFile(filepath);
    var sizeinbytes = thefile.size;
} else {
    var sizeinbytes = document.getElementById(uploaderName).files[0].size;
}

return sizeinbytes;
```

}

```
function validateFileSize6(source, arguments) {
arguments.IsValid = (getFileSize("uplCollection6") <= sizeLimit);
```

}

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jesse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `Display="None"` to the `CustomValidator` resolves the issue *properly*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what's causing this, but I found a weird fix for it:

The remove button calls the function `clearFileInputField()`:

```
function clearFileInputField(tagId) {
    document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML =
                document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML;
}
```

Looks weird, but it basically replaces the `fileUpload` with a fresh one. I noticed that if I click this button *before* I selected a file, it worked as expected. Again, I'm not sure why (and if anybody knows, please share), but I added a call to this function to the `$document.ready()` statement, and the problem goes away.